# Issue when copying cells (defaults to mm/dd/yyyy when im wanting dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below that looks for any changes and finds the match on the other sheet and updates any changes, however the dates when transferred over go from the UK formatting of dd/mm/yyyy to the US style date of mm/dd/yyyy making all the dates in the sheet incorrect.

Could someone help and advise how I make it stay the same way? Thanks!"

```
 Dim s1rw As Long, s2rw As Long, col As Long, endcol As Long    
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select  
With Sheets("Sheet2")  
s2rw = 2 ' Adjust to first data row #  
endcol = .Cells(s2rw - 1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column  
Do Until .Cells(s2rw, 1).Value = "" ' Loop through case #s  
s1rw = 0  
On Error Resume Next  
s1rw = Cells.Find(What:=.Cells(s2rw, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row  
On Error GoTo 0  
If s1rw > 0 Then ' Found case #  
For col = 1 To endcol ' Loop through columns  
If Cells(s1rw, col).Value <> "" Then  
.Cells(s2rw, col).Value = Cells(s1rw, col).Value  
 End If  
 Next  
 End If  
    Rows(s2rw).Delete  
 s2rw = s2rw + 1  
Loop  
 .Select  
 End With
```

Comment: I might overlook but I do not see any date format pieces in the code.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: Do you have Excel set up to be localized to the UK?

Answer (score 0):

The `Range.NumberFormat()` method for changing the format of your cells will allow you to set your own custom formatting within the VBA code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401%28v=office.15%29.aspx